# Why should the spelling checker mark Magento as an error?

Tags: discussion, magento, community

How difficult will it be to add **Magento** to the dictionary on this platform? 
It feels awkward and really bad to realise the spelling checker here does not recognise **Magento** as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary is a feature in your browser. You can add "Magento" locally to it.

Comment: Oh nice, I wonder how I missed this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Everyone are using the browsers like Google chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE and etc...
2. These all browsers will includes so many number of the words in dictionary.
3. Coming to Magento, This word is not included into that. That's the reason, Magento is showing up to us as mistake.
4. If we write Magneto instead of Magento, That will show that word as correct one.
5. We have to add that word "**Magento**" at all of our PC's in the way of Add to Dictionary.

That's It.